# Table Layout creation in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm new to android. I want to retrieve employee details from database and want to display those data into table layout in weekly basis. for that i want to create table layout with fixed header column like employee name, employee id, employee work status on first week,second week,third week,fourth week etc. and dynamic rows means number of employees is unknown.

How to create this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create Static Headers using Table Layout and than create Dynamic Table Layout inside your Database query which is retrieving your data on weekly basis.

And if you want add First week and Second week Separate header on table than use some trick.

Try this.

Comment: Google it man and try some code by yourself and if you have any problem in that than post it. I will help you.